# subset a dataframe in R within a specific time range

Tags: r, dataframe, date, subset

I have a dataframe, called dataBase, that contains many rows and columns. One of the columns contains dates (called date), whereas the remaining columns numeric values. A simplified representation is given below:

```
dataBase$date

"30/06/2020" "27/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "28/08/2020" "30/06/2020"
"28/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "01/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "01/08/2020"
"01/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "30/06/2020" "01/08/2020" "30/06/2020"
```

with the following class

```
    class(dataBase$date)#"character"
```

What I want to do, is to keep the rows of the dataframe for which the dates are within a range, let's say "01/01/2020"-"31/12/2020". (Hint: these dates might not appear explicitly in the date column, just serve as border dates)

I have tried different things. One was using the following commands:

```
DATE1 <- as.Date("01/01/2020")
DATE2 <- as.Date("31/12/2020")
TEST <- dataBase[dataBase$date >= DATE1 & dataBase$date <= DATE2,]
```

or

```
TEST <- subset(dataBase, date > as.Date("01/01/2020") & date < as.Date("31/12/2020"))
```

The dataframe remained unaffected by the above commands.

Eventually,  I had to sort the dataframe based on the dates of the date column and use "match" in order to get the corresponding positions:

```
    test4 <- dataBase[order(as.Date(dataBase$date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]
    forwrd <- sort(as.Date(test4$date, format="%d/%m/%Y"),decreasing = FALSE)
    forwrd <- format(as.Date(forwrd),'%d/%m/%Y')
    rev <- sort(as.Date(test4$date, format="%d/%m/%Y"),decreasing = TRUE)
    rev <- format(as.Date(rev),'%d/%m/%Y')
    start_period = "07/01/2020";end_period = "28/08/2020"
    ind_start<-match(start_period, forwrd)
    ind_end<-length(rev)-match(end_period,rev)+1
    test4_sub <- test4[ind_start:ind_end,];
```

which gave me the range of the rows (ind_start - ind_end)
I wanted to ask if there is a simpler way to do that. And why using the first two approaches did not work for me.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and consider accepting answers to the questions you have asked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
dataBase %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  filter(date >= "2020-07-30" & date <= "2020-08-30")
              a       date
V12 -0.23017749 2020-08-28
V13  1.55870831 2020-08-01
V21  0.07050839 2020-08-27
V32 -1.26506123 2020-08-01
V41 -0.44566197 2020-08-28
V43  0.35981383 2020-08-01
V52  0.11068272 2020-08-01
```

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
dataBase <- data.frame(a = rnorm(15), date = unlist(read.table(text = '"30/06/2020" "27/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "28/08/2020" "30/06/2020"
"28/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "01/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "01/08/2020"
"01/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "30/06/2020" "01/08/2020" "30/06/2019"')))
```

Comment: Dear Chris Ruehlemann and @Base_R_Best_R, thank you both for the very useful help. Both methods are working and are elegant! I have upvoted both of you.

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes. Did you know you can also accept an answer? Choose the answer that you like best and click the tick in the left upper corner of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in correctly specifying the date format. I also changed the last date to one that is outside your date range otherwise the `data.frame()` would have remained the same.

**Code**

```
# First convert from charactert to date

dataBase$date <- as.Date(dataBase$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

# then find the boolean vector for subsetting

bool <- dataBase$date < as.Date("2020-12-31") & dataBase$date > as.Date("2020-01-01")

# finally use that for subsetting 

dataBase[bool, ]

#              a       date
# V11  1.8071121 2020-06-30
# V12  0.1294905 2020-08-28
# V13 -0.8860187 2020-08-01
# V21 -1.5073589 2020-08-27
# V22  1.2067775 2020-06-30
# V23  1.1733465 2020-06-30
# V31  0.7798806 2020-06-30
# V32 -0.8435670 2020-08-01
# V33  0.8572508 2020-06-30
# V41 -2.3080748 2020-08-28
# V42  1.4869950 2020-06-30
# V43  0.1705372 2020-08-01
# V51  1.8373611 2020-06-30
# V52  0.5101801 2020-08-01
```

**Data**

```
dataBase <- data.frame(a = rnorm(15), date = unlist(read.table(text = '"30/06/2020" "27/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "28/08/2020" "30/06/2020"
"28/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "01/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "01/08/2020"
"01/08/2020" "30/06/2020" "30/06/2020" "01/08/2020" "30/06/2019"')))

dataBase

#              a       date
# V11  1.8071121 30/06/2020
# V12  0.1294905 28/08/2020
# V13 -0.8860187 01/08/2020
# V21 -1.5073589 27/08/2020
# V22  1.2067775 30/06/2020
# V23  1.1733465 30/06/2020
# V31  0.7798806 30/06/2020
# V32 -0.8435670 01/08/2020
# V33  0.8572508 30/06/2020
# V41 -2.3080748 28/08/2020
# V42  1.4869950 30/06/2020
# V43  0.1705372 01/08/2020
# V51  1.8373611 30/06/2020
# V52  0.5101801 01/08/2020
# V53 -0.9052635 30/06/2019
```